# GridLayout not working in JPanel

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, layout-manager, grid-layout

I'm trying to add a `JButton` to my `JPanel` multiple times using a `GridLayout`. For some reason though, every time I run the program it only shows 1 button.

Here's the code:

```
    jPLeft = new JPanel();
    jPLeft.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(600,500));
    jPLeft.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    jPLeft.setLayout(new GridLayout(2,2));
    jPLeft.setComponentOrientation(ComponentOrientation.LEFT_TO_RIGHT);
    window.add(jPLeft, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    imageSand = new ImageIcon("..\\CSY1020\\src\\resources\\sand.jpg");
    jBSand = new JButton(imageSand);
    jPLeft.add(jBSand);
    jPLeft.add(jBSand);
    jPLeft.add(jBSand);
    jPLeft.add(jBSand);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A `Component` can only be added once, and can only have 1 parent `Container`

```
imageSand = new ImageIcon("..\\CSY1020\\src\\resources\\sand.jpg");
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    JButton jBSand = new JButton(imageSand);
    jPLeft.add(jBSand);
    jPLeft.add(jBSand);
    jPLeft.add(jBSand);
    jPLeft.add(jBSand);
}
```

Comment: Actually, a component can be added multiple times, but will only have a single parent, removing it from its previous container - nitpick I know ;)